# Xpath with regex in Robot Frameworks XML library

Tags: xml, xpath, robotframework

I need to find all elements in huge xml, that has tag '`WOR`' and attr `distName`.

Value matches

```
MNL-\d+/AAA-\d+
```

e.g. `<WOR distName="MNL-123/AAA-4" />`
Hovever i cannot figure out, how to properly use that in RFs XML Library, [documentation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/XML.html) does have no info about it too.
I've tried to use Keyword 'Evaluate Xpath', but my search still is bad:

```
Library  XML  use_lxml=True
Evaluate Xpath  ${XML}  //WOR[re:match(@distName, "MNL-[0-9]+/AAA-[0-9]+")]
```

Comment: Don't tell us it's huge, tell us whether its 10Mb or 10Gb.

Comment: You should look in your documentation link for `Finding elements with xpath`, I think you might do something wrong.

Comment: Size of xml has nothing to issue. Finding elements with xpath was checked, but it's not same as finding elements with xpath using regex. There is no info about regex in xpath.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to compose xpath to match full or partial attribute value.

Full:

```
//WOR[@distName = 'MNL-123/AAA-4']
```

Partial with one part of the attribute:

```
//WOR[contains(@distName, 'MNL')]
```

Partial with two parts of the attribute:

```
//WOR[contains(@distName, 'MNL')][contains(@distName, 'AAA')]
```